# Vertical Spacing between headings in nested multicol List

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, multicol, nesting

Hi I have the following MWE and would like to know if using `\\` is BP or if there is a clear/better way to achieve the spacing between each headings. General opinions on the look of this are welcomed as well.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \setlist[itemize]{wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep,before=\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}}
    \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=1ex,leftmargin=*]
        \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
            \\
        \end{itemize}
        \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \\
        \end{itemize}
        \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \vfill\null
            \columnbreak
        \end{itemize}
    \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \\
        \end{itemize}
    \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \\
        \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but what does BP mean? British Petroleum?

Comment: In my understanding it is best practice, but if it is not commonly used, it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I'm not very fluent  at Acronym… More seriously, are you sure you don't want  *horizontal* enumerate (I mean the layout would be: 1.  Heading 2. Heading (nextline)3. Heading 4. Heading, &c.

Comment: You are talking about `tasks` i guess? What would that look like for my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `parsep` to `3.5ex` seems to achieve what you want, without the use of added blank lines `\\`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper, includehead, left=3.5cm, right=1.7cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}



\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \setlist[itemize]{wide =0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep,before=\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}}
    \begin{enumerate}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=-1ex,partopsep=1ex,parsep=3.5ex,leftmargin=*]
        \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 2
        \end{itemize}
        \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
        \end{itemize}
        \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \item Item 1
            \vfill\null
            \columnbreak
        \end{itemize}
    \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \end{itemize}
    \item Heading
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 1
        \end{itemize}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]